# How to tilt/change angle of view/camera from ortho in MapServer or OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, mapserver, viewshed, orthorectification, viewer

I am wondering if there is a way of changing the angle of the camera in MapServer from Ortho to a 60 degree (+-10) angle.

Perhaps this is an extensive modulation of Google Maps?

I could imagine that with some transformation of the map, this could be achieved by changing, not the angle of view, but the angle of map. So instead of looking at a flat 2d map, then the angle of map could be made by changing the "latitude" of the spheral globe. I then assume distortions of the projection would be an issue, even on a local scale.